# Making view controller appear on beginTextFieldEditing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I have a view and a view controller that does an address search. In another view, I have a text field. When that text field is edited, I want the view with this address search to appear/slide up. When the user is done entering things into that view I need the view to disappear and some combination of the things in the fields in that view to appear in the original text field.

How do I do this?

I realize that I have a few options. I can do this -

```
    self.searchBar.inputView = addressView;
```

But this seems wrong because the view should be a 'dumb' thing that simply renders in response to changes in data. Further - can a uiview have delegates?(My view controller is implementing a table delegate and a search bar delegate). Also this would involve me rewriting the view and view controller as just a view.

I guess I could also push the view controller onto the navigation controller of the view with the text field, but I'm not sure how I would display the formatted string in the text field (how does this view know when the other view is done?)

Answer (score 0):

Do this
On click of textfield (in `textDidChange` method) you can either push your search view if you
 are using navigation controller OR present search view modal using `presentModalViewController` method.

You will need to declare some string variable in your search view controller, which you will initialize before pushing it or 
presenting modally.

When you are done with search you can inform your previous view either by using

1. posting `NSNotification`
2. `Protocol` (delegate mechanism)
3. Having variable in parent which you will set using `self.presentingViewController.yourVariable`